# i have string which i want to split() in multiple delimiters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

```
"2+3-8*5"
 2
 3
 8
 5
```

how to split this string and save different variable

Comment: So you want to split the expression '2+3-8*5' into '2, 3, 8, 5'?

Comment: `"2+3-8*5".split(/(?:\+|\-|\*)/)`

Comment: Put that in the answer section @Adam

Comment: `str.split(/[-+*]/)`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can split your string into an array for multiple delimiters.

```js
var strVal = "2+3-8*5";

var resp = strVal.split(/(?:\+|\-|\*)/);

console.log("Resp: " , resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gufran solution is great with regex. If you don't want to use regex you can use `isNaN` with loop.

```js
var str = "2+3-8*5";
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(str.charAt(i), 10))) {
    result.push(str.charAt(i));
  }
}
console.log(result);
```